# Django: use custom methods for queryset values()

Tags: django, django-admin, django-queryset

I am trying to use a custom method from a model as field in value method of QuerySet object.

The model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field1
    field2
    field3
    ...

    def custom_method(self):
        return 'somestring'
```

In another module, I am trying this:

```
MyModel.objects.all().values('field1', 'field2', 'custom_method').annotate(field3Tot= Sum('field3'))
```

I need to group the sum by *field1*, *field2* and the **custom_method**. Is this possible or I have to use only "real" fields like *field1*...?

Comment: As far as I know you are limited to the "real" fields which are the "model-field-definitions". Maybe a custom field could be a solution for you but I am not sure about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible now.
Django queryset converts your query expression to SQL, so convert custom method to SQL is too complex task.

You can implement custom field expression by [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#extra) method of queryset.
For example:

```
MyModel.objects.extra(select={'custom_field': "'some string or expr'"})
.values('field1', 'field2', 'custom_field')
```

But there is not possible to use `annotate` here, queryset raise `FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'custom_field' into field.` Grouping will have peform by python.

Another way - use [raw qerysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries)
For example:

```
MyModel.objects.raw("select max(id) as id, 'some string or expr' as custom_field 
from table group by custom_field")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't.
`values()` return resultset as per fields passed into it for that model.
It will not work if if you will pass any custom methods.

Comment: Then how should we solve this , any ides would be great. thanks

Answer (score 3):

maybe there is a more complex way of overriding/modifying the QuerySet class

I found my solution to this problem was just to make an iterator

```
class Person(models.Model):

    first_name = models.CharField(...)
    last_name = models.CharField(...)
    dob = models.DateTimeField(...)

    def full_name(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name
```

Then I was trying to make a json response to mix fields and methods

```
 jsonresponse = []
 for person in Person.objects.all():
     jsonresponse.append({"name": person.full_name(), "birthdate" :  person.dob})

 return JsonResponse({"results":jsonresponse})
```